# Prove that $3^n > 2n^2 + 3n$ for $n \in [4,\infty) \cap\mathbb{N}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

If $n$ is a natural number $n\ge 4$, prove that $3^n > 2n^2 + 3n$

I assume I am supposed to use induction. The base $n=4$ step is clear, but how do I prove the inductive step. I tried several things including comparing $f(n+1)/f(n)$ and $f(n+1)-f(n)$ but they didn't seem to help. A hint would be great!

Comment: Hint: $3^{n+1} = 3(3^{n}) > 3(2n^{2}+3n)$ by the inductive hypothesis. Now can you show that $3(2n^{2}+3n) > 2(n+1)^{2} + 3(n+1)$ for $n \geq 4$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$3^{n+1}=3(3^n)>\overbrace{3(2n^2+3n)}^{\text{inductive assumption}}=6n^2+9n=\overbrace{6n^2+7n+2n>6n^2+7n+5}^{\textrm{for n>2.5}}$
$>2n^2+7n+5=2(n+1)^2+3(n+1)$

Comment: @AWertheim fixed. Cheers for that

Comment: Thanks! Nice answer, +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

I.H.: $3^n>2n^2+3n$. Consider $2(n+1)^2+3(n+1)=2n^2+2+4n+3n+3=2n^2+5+7n$. Then, $3^{n+1}=3\times 3^n>3(2n^2+3n)=6n^2+9n$ by the induction hypothesis.
Since for $n\geq4$, $6n^2+9n>2n^2+5+7n$ ($6n^2+9n>2n^2+5+7n\implies 4n^2+2n>5$, which is true for $n>0.895$, and hence is true for $n\geq4$), the statement is true for $n+1$.

Comment: thanks! This is a perfect proof as well

Comment: @clay Thank you. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Write

$$ f(n) = 3^n - 2 n^2 - 3 n$$

Then

$$ f(n+1) = 3^{n+1} - 2 \big(n+1\big)^2 - 3 \big(n+1) $$

which can be written as

$$ f(n+1) = 3 \big( 3^n - 2 n^2 -  3 n \big) + 6 n^2 + 9 n - 2 \big(n+1\big)^2 - 3\big(n+1)$$

So

$$ f(n+1) = 3 f(n) + 4 n^2 + 2 n - 5$$

Note that

$$ f(3) = 0 $$

And note that

$$ 4 n^2 + 2 n - 5 > 0 $$

for $n \ge 1$, whence

$$ f(n) > 0 $$

for $n \ge 4$,

therefore

$$ 3^n - 2 n^2 - 3 n > 0$$

for $n \ge 4$, or

$$ 3^n > 2 n^2 + 3 n$$

for $n \ge 4$.